# Java deployment tool and gxjarscanner

Tags: java, tomcat, war, genexus

With Genexus X Ev3U1, sample KB 'lightCRM' and only JAVA generator, I build the project without error. After, I use the JAVA deployment wizard to generate WAR with these options:

`Mains to deploy = home (Home) and no add classes.`

The generated context.xml in the war contains:

```
JarScanner classname=".com.genexus.webpanels.GXJarScanner".
```

But the war does not contain the GXJarScanner file.
If I try to deploy war file on my tomcat7 server, I get an error during deployment step

```
"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.genexus.webpanels.GXJarScanner ..."
```

I do not find any webpanel.* or JarScanner.* file in Genexus tree.

How to generate this war properly?
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Java 7 or higher? You can download the .jar file from here:

http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,8,77,O,E,0,,4458

... and add it in the new deployment you must do.

If you don't need the .jar file in your application, you also can change the Descriptor Type in the Deployment Wizard, using Generic Servlet v2.3

Hope this helps.